# use awk to search within a string and return result as variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

The code I have now

```
line=$(ps -A|awk '/$name/{print $1}')
```

doesn't seems working. What I want is use awk to search ps's output by process name and return the pid within my script

Comment: Often when pattern matching against ps(1), it helps to restrict the output to just those fields of interest, so as not to accidentally match against usernames or ttynames or whatever.  Try `ps -Awo pid=,comm=` on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
line=$(ps -A|awk -v name="$name" '$0 ~ name{print $1}')
```

See [here](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24) for the right ways to access the values of shell variables in awk scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
line=$(ps -A|awk '/'$name'/{print $1}')
```

You are missing extra quote `'` for `$name`

Comment: No. Never do this, it is unnecessary and will lead to cryptic errors in future.